# Add-PnPView - Sort by Ascending order?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp

```
# CREATE VIEW QUERY
$Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Name' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>"

# CREATE VIEWS FOR PLAYER BIO
Add-PnPView `
  -List 'Player Bios' `
  -Title 'All Players' `
  -Fields 'Name', 'Date of Birth', 'Squad Number', 'Player Position', 'Club' `
  -Query $Query 

# SET VIEW AS DEFAULT
Set-PnPView `
 -List 'Player Bios'  `
 -Identity 'All Players' `
 -Values @{DefaultView=$True}
```

I am trying to sort by Name Ascending true, but this does not seem to be working. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort in descending order try using this:

```
$Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Name' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>"
```

To sort in ascending order try using this:

```
$Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Name' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>"
```

**Official documentation**: [Add-PnPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps).

**Update**:

If you are trying to do this in **document library** then try this:

```
$Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>"
```

Comment: Nope still not working :( I am trying to sort a-z on the name field

Comment: Check the internal name of `Name field and use it.

Comment: a-z is ascending order and not descending. Can you check and confirm what is the internal name of your `Name` field? Are you trying to create this view in document library?

Comment: Checked the name, <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /> - this fixed it :)

Comment: Great, please upvote( ^ ) and accept it as an answer if this helped you.

Comment: This only worked for me when I once I wrapped the query in the `<View><Query>` Query  `</Query></View>`

Answer (score 1):

The correct column name for this document library is `LinkFilename`. If its a SharePoint list, you need to use `LinkTitle`

Modify the query as below:

```
$Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /></OrderBy>"
```

Also, Add-PnPView supports `SetAsDefault` which if used sets the view as Default view as below:

```
Add-PnPView `
  -List 'Player Bios' `
  -Title 'All Players' `
  -Fields 'Name', 'Date of Birth', 'Squad Number', 'Player Position', 'Club' `
  -Query $Query
  -SetAsDefault
```

Comment: Thank you!! - Name='LinkFilename' - This was screwing me over :P

Comment: Welcome, you can accept it as answer if it helped you ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

when i edit my list with PowerShell, i have this query

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy>
```

when you want (Ascending true) do not add parameter ascending, like this for title

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" Ascending="FALSE" /><FieldRef Name="Title" /></OrderBy>
```